# Canvas grid gets blurry at different zoom levels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grid

I am trying to create a simple canvas grid which will fit itself to the player's current zoom level, but also to a certain canvas height/width proportional screen limit. Here is what I got so far:

JS:

```
var bw = window.innerWidth / 2; //canvas size before padding
var bh = window.innerHeight / 1.3; //canvas size before padding
//padding around grid, h and w
var pW = 30;
var pH = 2;
var lLimit = 0; //9 line limit for both height and width to create 8x8

//size of canvas - it will consist the padding around the grid from all sides + the grid itself. it's a total sum
var cw = bw + pW;
var ch = bh + pH;

var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).appendTo('body');

var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

function drawBoard(){ 

     for (var x = 0; lLimit <= 8; x += bw / 8) { //handling the height grid 
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, bh);
        lLimit++;
    }

    for (var x = 0; lLimit <= 17; x += bh / 8) { //handling the width grid
        context.moveTo(0, x); //begin the line at this cord
        context.lineTo(bw, x); //end the line at this cord
        lLimit++;
    }
    //context.lineWidth = 0.5; what should I put here?
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
}

drawBoard();
```

Now, I succeeded at making the canvas to be at the same proportional level for each screen resolution zoom level. this is part of what I am trying to achieve. I also try to achieve thin lines, which will look the same at all different zooming levels, and of course to remove the blurriness. right now the thickness
of the lines change according to the zooming levels and are sometimes blurry.

Here is jsFiddle (although the jsFiddle window itself is small so you will barely notice the difference):

https://jsfiddle.net/wL60jo5n/

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you say zoom levels, do you mean zoom built into most browsers (using control+mwheel up/down)?

Comment: Yes. window.innerWidth considers the current zoom level of the user as the page loads.

Comment: A live example of the grid system I try to achieve: http://slither.io/ no matter at what zoom level you enter the webpage, or even when you zoom in and out during the game, the grid system looks the same.

Comment: js2dx.com is a library that attempts to address the issue of blur in "canvas" tag.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent blur, you should account for [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) when setting dimensions of your `canvas` element (and account for that dimensions during subsequent drawing, of course).

`width` and `height` properties of your `canvas` element should contain values that are proportionally higher than values in CSS properties of the same names. This can be expressed e.g. as the following function:

```js
function setCanvasSize(canvas, width, height) {
    var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio,
        style = canvas.style;

    style.width  = '' + (width  / ratio) + 'px';
    style.height = '' + (height / ratio) + 'px';

    canvas.width  = width;
    canvas.height = height;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove blurry effect on canvas zoom/scale i used `image-rendering: pixelated` in css

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using **decimal values** to draw. Both the canvas width and the position increments in your `drawBoard()` loop use fractions. The canvas is a bitmap surface, not a vectorial drawing. When you set the width and height of the canvas, you set the actual number of pixels stored in memory. That value cannot be decimal (browsers will probably just trim the decimal part). When you try to draw at decimal positions, the canvas will use pixel interpolation to avoid aliasing, hence the occasional blur.

See a version where I round `x` before drawing:
https://jsfiddle.net/hts7yybm/

Try rounding the values just before you draw them, but not in your actual logic. That way, the imprecision won't stack as the algorithm keeps adding to the value.

```
function drawBoard(){
  for (var x = 0; lLimit <= 8; x += bw / 8) {
    var roundedX = Math.round(x);
    context.moveTo(roundedX, 0);
    context.lineTo(roundedX, bh);
    lLimit++;
  }

  for (var x = 0; lLimit <= 17; x += bh / 8) {
    var roundedX = Math.round(x);
    context.moveTo(0, roundedX);
    context.lineTo(bw, roundedX);
    lLimit++;
  }
  context.lineWidth = 1; // never use decimals
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();
}
```

---

EDIT: I'm pretty sure all browsers behave as if the canvas was an img element, so there's no way to prevent aliasing when the user zooms with their browser's zoom function, other than with prefixed css. And even then, I'm not sure the browsers's zoom feature takes that into account.

```
canvas {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

Also, make sure the canvas doesn't have any CSS-set dimensions. That only stretches the image after it's been drawn instead of increasing the drawing surface. If you want to fill a block with the canvas by giving it 100% width and height, then you need some JS to compute the CSS-given height and width and set the value of the canvas's width and height property based on that. Then you can make your own implementation of a zoom function within your canvas drawing code, but depending on what you're doing it might be overkill.

Comment: I applied what you did, but it didn't work. Put your zooming level over 200%, then refresh the page. Then put it on 300% and refresh. You will notice changes for each zooming level; it gets thicker or thiner. the test should be performed on a regular HTML window, not jsFiddle as the differences are not noticeable.